# How do i write a loop that copies and paste from the clipboard

Tags: autohotkey

Im trying to write a loop that copies and paste from a clipboard i titled InitialWords.txt what i acutally want is for it to copy the words line by line and press the F2 key after each word. Heres what i tried-

```
Loop , read C:\InitialWords.txt
 { 
    Loop , parse , A_LoopReadLine , %A_Tab%
    {
     clipboard= %A_LoopField%
   send ^v
   send {F2}
    }   
 }
```

Thanks id appreciate any help.

Comment: Does it work manually?  If you copy a word from the text file, and press Ctrl-V when the game is active; does that work?

Comment: Yea it works manually. But instead of writing the words vertically, it writes them horizontally so the words dont count ie it supposed 2 write them like
header
headers
adheres
but instead it writes header headers adheres so the words dont count.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you were missing a comma after `Loop, Read`.  You can also bypass using the clipboard altogether.

```
Loop, Read, C:\InitialWords.txt 
{ 
    Loop, Parse, A_LoopReadLine, %A_Tab% 
    { 
        Send %A_LoopField%
        send {F2} 
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this in a certain application? Programmatically, this is sound and works in a text editor (substituting ``n` for `{F2}`).

Comment: Yes its 4 an application. Its for a game called gowords. They give u words like headersdoig then u have to form words from it but i use an anagram application which shows me all the possible words so i copy them to the InitialWords.txt and thats why i need the loop to copy the words line by line and the F2 is the send button after you type each word.
 Tried your code in the normal text editor and in the game but it didnt still work...

Answer (score 0):

```
Loop, Read, InitialWords.txt
{
   Loop, Parse, A_LoopReadLine, %A_Tab%
   {
        SendPlay % A_LoopField
        Sleep % strLen(A_LoopField)*2
        SendPlay, {F2}
        Sleep 300
   }
}
```